# Is compressed class space in Java8 proportional to heap?

Tags: java

I am receiving an OutOfMemoryError on "Compressed class space". I understand that the default is 1gb and that it can be disabled and that I can increase the space. What I would like to find out is whether the usage of compressed class space area changes with the size of the heap. ie, if I have a 512mb heap will it use around the same **Compressed Class Space** as say a heap with 16gb ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Compressed class space" is part of metaspace.  Changing the size of this region of metaspace does not directly affect the heap size.  However, it does consume virtual memory, and this could limit the memory available for the regular Java heap.

> If I have a 512mb heap will it use around the same space as say a heap with 16gb?

Probably yes.  Compressed class space contains class *code* ... not instances (objects).  In a normal program, the number of classes used and their size is constant, and does not correlate with the number or size of the instances.

One exception to this is if your application over-uses / misuses dynamic proxies.  In fact, that could be the root cause of your OOME's!

Comment: Actually, I am trying to understand whether the size of the heap affects the compressed class space. A larger heap would translate to more number of objects ; would that in turn translate to a larger compressed class space ?

Comment: No it wouldn't.

Comment: Stephen C going over some of your posts and some other posts on stackoverflow, its become clear to me that setting -XX:MetaspaceSize will cause a GC to occur which in turn will eventually reduce the Metaspace used (since the GC will collect the objects from the heap etc). Will setting this limit also reduce the usage of CompressedClassSpace ? If not, will setting -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize  help ?

Comment: If you are interested in learning what class space is, why it is called compressed class space and why it is used since Java 8, you can read Compressed OOPS book.  https://javaperformanceoptimization.com/